# Subfigures within minipage

Tags: subfig

I have 5 figures, which I want to display in one page, after dividing it in three minipages. Idellay I have 2 subfigures in the first minipage, 2 in the second one, and only one in the third minipage center-aligned.

I tried the following:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[paper=letterpaper,left=1.0in,right=1.0in,top=0.25in,bottom=1.0in,]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{minipage}{03.\textheight}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[a]{\includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth] {./pngs/profile_L_3lambda_max_1wl_0.png}
   \label{fig:subfig1}
 }%
\end{subfigure}
 \begin{subfigure}[b]{\includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{./pngs/profile_L_3lambda_max_1wl_dft_0.png}
   \label{fig:subfig2}
 }%
\end{subfigure}
\label{fig:myfigure}
\end{minipage}

\begin{minipage}{03.\textheight}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[c]{\includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth] {./pngs/profile_L_3lambda_max_1wl_0.png}
   \label{fig:subfig1}
 }%
\end{subfigure}
 \begin{subfigure}[d]{\includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{./pngs/profile_L_3lambda_max_1wl_dft_0.png}
   \label{fig:subfig2}
 }%
\end{subfigure}
\label{fig:myfigure}
\end{minipage}

\begin{minipage}{03.\textheight}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[f]{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth] {./pngs/profile_L_3lambda_max_1wl_0.png}
   \label{fig:subfig1}
 }%
\end{subfigure}
\caption{My caption}
\end{minipage}

\end{figure}
```

Unfortunately, the result is totally hopeless. Any suggestion on how to fix it? Thanks in advance

Comment: Watch out, not `\begin{minipage}{03.\textheight}`, it is `\begin{minipage}{0.3\textheight}`

Comment: @ferahfeza. You are right. thanks. However, Figures come one after the other. I cannot obtain two figures in the first minipage, two in the second and one in the third. Any suggestion on this issue?

Comment: Do you want to obtain the two figures side by side in minipage?

Comment: delete empty lines between `minipage`s. however, do you really need `minipage`s? you can obtain desired result also without using them.

Comment: @ferahfeza Indeed.

Comment: @Dario, look at this nice answer : https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/261301/31034

Comment: @Zarko I deleted the space in the between and it worked. However, the last figure is not center-aligned, but it goes below the column on the left. How can I obtain this?

Comment: @ferahfeza Thanks for the suggestion. I am almost there. The last point is that the last figure is not centered, but it goes below the first column.

Comment: Solved! In the last minipage I substitute \begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth} with \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}

Comment: @Dario, see my answer. test it since temporary is not possible to upload images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- the package `subfigure` is obsolete. it is replaced with `subfig`. however, even better is to use the `subcaption` package.
- i would not use `minipage` for grouping your sub figures, this can be done without them:

  ```
  \documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
  \usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
  \usepackage{subcaption}
  \usepackage{amsmath}
  \usepackage[paper=letterpaper,
              left=1.0in,right=1.0in,
              top=0.25in,bottom=1.0in,]{geometry}

  \begin{document}
      \begin{figure}
  \centering
      \begin{subfigure}{0.45\linewidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{./pngs/profile_L_3lambda_max_1wl_0.png}
  \caption{}
  \label{fig:subfig1}
      \end{subfigure}\hfil
      \begin{subfigure}{0.45\linewidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{./pngs/profile_L_3lambda_max_1wl_dft_0.png}
  \caption{}
  \label{fig:subfig2}
      \end{subfigure}

  \smallskip
       \begin{subfigure}{0.45\linewidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{./pngs/profile_L_3lambda_max_1wl_0.png}
  \caption{}
  \label{fig:subfig3}
      \end{subfigure}\hfil
       \begin{subfigure}{0.45\linewidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{./pngs/profile_L_3lambda_max_1wl_dft_0.png}
  \caption{}
  \label{fig:subfig4}
      \end{subfigure}

  \smallskip
       \begin{subfigure}{0.45\linewidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{./pngs/profile_L_3lambda_max_1wl_0.png}
  \caption{}
  \label{fig:subfig5}
      \end{subfigure}

  \caption{My caption}
  \label{fig:my-figures}
      \end{figure}
  See Fig.~\ref{fig:my-figures}, particularly sub figure \ref{fig:subfig5} \dots
  \end{document}
  ```

[image]

Comment: @Dario, you are welcome!